# How to convert "2016-11-08T13:04:16.5260175Z" this into apex datetime like "11/8/2016 1:04 PM"

Tags: apex, visualforce, java

I need to convert "2016-11-08T13:04:16.5260175Z" this one into DateTime format like "11/8/2016 1:04 PM". Please help me.

Comment: Is it a string field? In that case you might need to extract the date information to use for DateTime.parse method

Answer (score 3):

I think that the most reliable method is to use the JSON.deserialize method. This accounts for time zones etc and is invoked like this:

```
DateTime result = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"' + '2016-11-08T13:04:16.5260175Z' + '"', DateTime.class);
System.debug(result);
```

Note that I've put an extra set of double quotes around the string you want to parse. JSON is going to expect those, and you'll get odd results without them.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = '2016-11-08T13:04:16.5260175Z';
s = s.substring(0,s.indexOf('.'));
s= s.replace('T',' ');
datetime d= datetime.valueof(s);
```

Comment: You may want to explain what it is you're actually doing here. This wouldn't even compile because you're declaring two strings, `s`, with the same name.

Comment: edited the code.

Comment: Try explaining the code too? What does `s.substring` do for someone who's never used it before? What does `s.replace` do? What are we doing when setting `Datetime d`?